# Como acessar o stream antes da compressão ser executada via Global.asax?

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc, request, compressão

Da lado do servidor aplico compressão quando possível:

```
public MvcApplication()
    {
        this.BeginRequest += OnRequestBegin;
        this.PreSendRequestContent += OnPreSendRequestContent;
    }

    private void OnPreSendRequestContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (app == null || !app.Request.IsLocal || app.Context == null)
            return;
        var headers = app.Context.Response.Headers;
        headers.Remove("Server");
    }

    private void OnRequestBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewServiceLocator.Instance = new ViewServiceLocator(InjectionHelper.DefaultContainer);

        var app = sender as HttpApplication;

        string encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");
        if (encodings != null)
        {
            encodings = encodings.ToLower();
            AddCompression(app.Response, encodings);
        }
    }

    // Implement HTTP compression
    private void AddCompression(HttpResponse response, string encodings)
    {
        if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(response.Filter, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
        }
        else if (encodings.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(response.Filter, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
    }
```

Enquanto do lado do cliente tenho um loading global e um loading que funciona por contexto:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        myApp.Request.Context = settings.context, jqXHR.url = settings.url;

        if (settings.global && (settings.context === "undefined" || settings.context !== "undefined" && !document.getElementById("main").contains(settings.context)))
            StartWait();
    },
    //Código removido para facilitar a leitura...
    xhr: function () {
        let xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest(), $context = $(myApp.Request.Context);

        if (myApp.Request.Context) {
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {

                console.log("progress", evt);
                console.log("progress", $context);
                console.log("lengthComputable", evt.lengthComputable);
                console.log("x-decompressed-content-length", evt.target.getResponseHeader('x-decompressed-content-length'));
                console.log("content-length", evt.target.getResponseHeader('content-length'));

                let contentLength;
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    contentLength = evt.total;
                } else {
                    contentLength = evt.target.getResponseHeader('content-length');
                }

                let percentComplete = evt.loaded / contentLength * 100;

                if (percentComplete === 100) {

                    console.log("progress-done", percentComplete);

                    DestroiLoadingContextual($context);
                }
            }, false);

            CriaLoadingContextual($context);
        }

        return xhr;
    }
});
```

**Meu problema**: Quando a requisição vem compactada do servidor, *evt.lengthComputable = false* e *evt.total = 0*, o *contentLength* vem com o valor do tamanho compactado, **mas** eu preciso da informação do tamanho **original**.

[Isso parece ser um problema já conhecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127654/why-is-progressevent-lengthcomputable-false)

Estou tentanto criar um header "**x-decompressed-content-length**" informando o valor original, no *BeginRequest* como no *PreSendRequestContent*, quando tento acessar o **OutputStream** do *Response* para obter o **Length**, recebo uma [exceção](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604774/datastream-length-and-position-threw-an-exception-of-type-system-notsupportede);

O que fiz de errado ou alguém conhece alguma outra possível solução?